# How to pass node as prop to component in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Trying to separate logic from design.

The following is a simplified version of the problem I am trying to solve.

```js
import React, { ReactNode } from "react"

interface ChildProps {
  id: string
}

const Child = function (props: ChildProps) {
  return <div id={props.id} />
}

interface ParentProps {
  id: string
  node: ReactNode
}

const Parent = function (props: ParentProps) {
  return <props.node id={props.id} /> // Throws "JSX element type 'props.node' does not have any construct or call signatures.ts(2604)" error
}
```

Comment: How do you expect to pass in `node`? Are passing in a functional component like `node={MyComponent}` or rendered JSX like `node={<div>foo</div>}`?

Comment: @AlexWayne `node={MyComponent}` and forgot to mention I need to be able to set props of that node inside of the function block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ReactNode` is a type for rendered JSX, so you want to type your prop as a functional component,

```
interface TestProps {
  node: React.FC
}
```

Which then should work like you expect: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2&ssl=4&ssc=19&pln=4&pc=23#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wChTgA7GJKTdJOAFSQGcYAFHMVuAb1JwhcShAAmSAFyJiMAHQAxAMKkAvuTQRK7Zm3gBeOJgCulDMC1wAFGG6tpLdlwg8AlP0HCiMY1EpwAHlsXVjlRCTgAegA+NSA)

---

It's also a good best practice to render JSX components as a title-case JSX tag. This is easier to read in more complex components. Which makes this something like:

```
const Test = function (props: TestProps) {
    const Node = props.node
    return <Node />
}
```

---

If the component you want to accept takes an `id` property, you can specificy that in the props type for `node`.

```
interface TestProps {
    node: React.FC<{ id: number }>
}
```

Now you can just assign the prop as you would any other prop:

```
const Test = function(props: TestProps) {
    const Node = props.node
    return <Node id={123} />
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=9&pc=2#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wChTgA7GJKTdJOAFSQGcYAFHMVuAb1JwhcShAAmSAFyJiMAHQAxAMIAePnGBjplAK4gARrTgBfAHylj5NBErtmbeAF44mHZQzAbcABTrRE6QA5cUZjaRZ2LggeAEp+QWEiGB0oSjgVYIkNMUc+AEYAJgBmYzgAenNjIA)

---

Lastly, you could go crazy with generics and infer the prop types of `node`, and make the wrapper component accept all the props that node accepts, no matter what they are.

```
interface TestProps<P> {
    node: React.FC<P>
    nodeProps: P
}

const Test = function<P>({ node: Node, nodeProps }: TestProps<P>) {
    return <Node {...nodeProps} />
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2&ssl=17&ssc=3&pln=12&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wChTgA7GJKTdJOAFSQGcYAFHMVgHg4B8cAN6k44uJQgATJAC5ExGADoAYgGF+AsRKmyuEHgo6kAvuTQRK7Zm3gBeOJgCulDMCtaAFMMkz5cABy-gA0fvrcrHCmCizsBjxaAJQiOuJEMM5QlHC8wbIiykV6SAmspnAA9NrmpJbW8ABWrAAecI68cTBp4Uj2wl5gkQq+NC0wCuxQVADm0Sn2QqISK3AZWTm8AsJDhqzKYzCmvNU9puYrJWX9o0jjCgDkmBAQD9Hm1UA)

Which is academically interesting, but not much different than just rendering passing in rendered JSX.

Comment: Thanks Alex, we’re getting close... how would you handle assigning `id={props.id}`? Currently `ChildProps` is not inferred.

Comment: If you're passing in props then you probably want to pass in rendered JSX. Are sure you don't want to do `node={<MyComponent id={id} />}` instead?

Comment: Perhaps I am not writing proper React code, but currently, `id` is not known by `Child` ahead of time and its design changes based on props defined by `Parent`.

Comment: Tried using `React.FunctionComponent<any>` and looks promising although I would favor if the type of `node` was somehow inferred.

Comment: Thanks for your help Alex!

Comment: Added one more option using generics, because generics are fun. And thanks for the tip on that link. Not there's much there public anyway :)